# How to loop over a multi-row/column range per column using Excel 2007 VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm looping to loop over a range with multiple rows and columns using Excel 2007 VBA.

I'm specifically trying to loop over a user selected range, and perform a calculation on each column in the range, and output the calculation two rows below each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the currently selected range by using

```
Application.Selection.Address
```

This will give you a range value (the Selection property returns a Range object) that will look something like "`$B$4:$J$20`".

Given you now have a range to work with, you can iterate across each column using something like:

```
For Each col In userSelectedRange.Columns

   ...

Next
```

The Columns property again returns a Range object that you can either iterate over further or perform other calculations on (your exact needs aren't too clear from your question).

To post the calculated result two rows above each column (e.g. a subtotal or similar), try using the Offset function:

```
Cells.Offset(-2, 0)
```

If you're able to provide more specifics around the sort of calculation you want, I may be able to add more detail into how you achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can do the calculations needed myself, I'm just very unfamiliar with how to select certain sets of cells from Excel. The calculations are either just a simple average of each column, and then subtracting the average from each element in the columns.

Comment: Does my answer provide enough help with how to iterate over sets of cells, or do you need more?  There are other properties and methods in VBA that allow you to work with ranges in different ways in Excel.

Comment: I believe I need to iterate over the Columns range, and then the Rows range to get the average of each column, yes? But when I try to do that, I'm encountering some trouble. Can I PM you with my code, or is it possible to insert it into comments?

Comment: Feel free to PM me.  You can get my email address through my profile, which will link you to my site.  Alternatively, go to http://card.ly/philwheeler